# Sqoop fails with unrecognized argument

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

I've multiple file in HDFS. Trying to load to Oracle. Using this script from long time. But recently same process giving me error. 
**Here is the code**:

```
#!/bin/bash

refDate=`date --date="2 days ago" "+%Y-%m-%d"`
func_data_load_to_dwh()
{
        date
        if [[ ! -z `hadoop fs -ls /data/dna_data/dna_daily_summary_data/pdate=${refDate}/*` ]]
        then
                file=`hadoop fs -ls /data/dna_data/dna_daily_summary_data/pdate=${refDate}/|grep dna_daily_summary_data |awk '{print $NF}'`
                sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//raxdw-scan:1628/raxdw --username schema_name --password 'password' --table TBL_DNA_DATA_DAILY_SUMMARY --export-dir ${file} --input-fields-terminated-by '|' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --direct
}
#_________________ main function ________________
        func_data_load_to_dwh
```

**Error Code:**

```
20/01/14 11:05:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /data/dna_data/dna_daily_summary_data/pdate=2020-01-12/f14873b51555a17d-946772b200000029_1797907225_data.0.
20/01/14 11:05:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --input-fields-terminated-by
20/01/14 11:05:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: |
20/01/14 11:05:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --lines-terminated-by
20/01/14 11:05:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: \n
20/01/14 11:05:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --direct
```

But If I run manually with single file from shell it runs perfectly:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//raxdw-scan:1628/raxdw --username schema_name --password 'password' --table TBL_DNA_DATA_DAILY_SUMMARY --export-dir /data/dna_data/dna_daily_summary_data/pdate=2020-01-12/784784ec62558fea-1d14102000000029_1144698661_data.0. --input-fields-terminated-by '|' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --direct
```

Bit strange because it worked before. All I did is to change the directory in `if` condition. Nothing else. Could you suggesnt anything

Comment: Few suggestions: print the "$file" to debug it. Also print the whole command instead of executing it. Just add the echo before sqoop.  Also it is a good practice to quote variables. For example "${file}" instead of ${file}.

Comment: In addition to above suggestions please try specifying the directory path in --export-dir instead of file if the entire files present under /data/dna_data/dna_daily_summary_data/pdate=2020-01-12 are to be exported.

--export-dir "/data/dna_data/dna_daily_summary_data/pdate=2020-01-12"